# line-height on input button only works with border on Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

`input[type="submit"]` buttons on Chrome and Safari seem to only respect a `line-height` property when combined with a `border` property.

Looking at the computed `line-height` value in Chrome's debugger shows the button with border having the expected computed value, whereas the button without the border has `line-height: normal`.

Firefox shows both versions respecting the `line-height` property.  Chrome and Safari do not.

As an added bonus, changing the elements from `input[type="submit"]` to `button` makes them work as expected.

Any ideas why this is happening?

CSS

```
.border { line-height: 3rem; border: solid 1px black; }
.noborder { line-height: 3rem; }
```

HTML

```
<input type="submit" class="border" value="input[type='submit'] with border" />
<input type="submit" class="noborder" value="input[type='submit'] without border" />
```

Screenshot
[image: input button with line-height and border versus input button with line-height without border]

Browsers Tested

- Firefox 73.0 - Works as expected.
- Google Chrome 80.0.3987.106 - Unexpected results.
- Safari 13.0.5 - Unexpected results.

Comment: You need to specifically override the button styling for Chrome to work (dunno, about Safari). Have a look at [this demo on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_form_button). Or do an online search for 'css style submit button'

Comment: It doesn't make sense, however, that adding a single style would cause a different style to kick in.  In the link you sent, comment out both `border` and `background-color`.  Only the outline of shorter buttons appear.  Now add back the `background-color` property and the buttons are now back to their padding-driven height.  It would seem the demo can be used to show the behaviour I'm asking about.

Comment: Do you mean you 'have been served' or do you need more help? Not clear from you reply....

Comment: I need help.  I would like to understand whether the observed behaviour is by design, and why, or whether it is a bug.  That way, we can devise appropriate work-arounds, and for which browsers.  I appreciate any insights.

Comment: Your question (and findings) already implies 'behaviour by design'. Go for control and create your own button style (even if it looks exactly like the html default one), this way you don't have to check each browser for differences.

Comment: Forgot to say thanks, Rene.  I followed your advise, took control, and feel much better about the design.

Comment: Better late than never, much appreciated though! 'When in doubt, take control' has always served me well.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use vertical-align: middle; instead of line-height.